# Gradle cannot find Android SDK

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When importing an existing Gradle-based Android project into IntelliJ, I'm receiving the following error:

[image: sdk error]

I also received that error with the path (set via `local.properties`) set to

```
/Users/chris/android-sdk-macosx
```

However, as you can see, that's where my Android SDK is installed:

[image]

[image]

And I have platform-22 installed as well:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have Android 22 installed? Gradle can give this error if your build.gradle specifies a version that you don't have

Comment: @TheoKanning, yep, check out the last screen shot. At least I believe I have it installed based on that directory and the android SDK manager (which I'll post in a second)